# Windows 7 post clean install questions

Tags: windows-7, installation

I installed a new HDD and installed Win7 Home Premium 32bit. The OS just has the basic drivers and nothing else. I wanna know

Which of the [following drivers](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=4168971&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=4074361&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4062#11360) do I really need? These are specific to my laptop.

The Aero system won't work. The troubleshooter says that the drivers do not support it. Why is it that drivers do not support it? Do I need the drivers from the above-mentioned list? Cause a lot are already installed I guess

I was told that  now if I were to uninstall the drivers from device manager, they won't reinstall automatically as they previously did. What is the solution?

I get error in device manager that drivers for PCI Simple Communications are missing. Help there as well

I don't use battery in my laptop as it has wornout. I was planning on using a UPS as the power goes quite frequently. The backup generator kicks in but supplies 300V instead of 220V. Advise please.

Configuration:
HP DV4-2126TX running Win7 Home Premium 32bit
ATI Radeon 4550 512MB Graphics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Download and install the latest version of HP Support Assistant](http://h18021.www1.hp.com/helpandsupport/hp-support-assistant.html), once installed run Support assistant, when it loads click the "Maintain" icon, another page will load, if scanning does not start click the "refresh" icon.

This will scan your system for software and drivers that need to be installed, the only one I recommend to skip is any Bios updates.

[image]

.

[image]

.

[image]

.

[image]

.

[image]

Comment: Your answer,as always, to-the-point and lucid!

Comment: Mine only asked for Atheros driver. I guess I will have to manually install the others

Comment: You might try again later in the week, HP is doing a massive update to their support servers due to the roll out of Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

> The Aero system won't work. The troubleshooter says that the drivers
>   do not support it. Why is it that drivers do not support it? Do I need
>   the drivers from the above-mentioned list?

This means you need to install the drivers for your `ATI Radeon 4550 512MB Graphics`

Comment: The problem is there are [drivers on ATI's website](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonaiw_vista32.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.36;2.4.1.3.37;2.4.1.3.39;2.4.1.3.38;2.4.1.3.40&lang=us&rev=&ostype=Windows%207%20-%2032-Bit%20Edition)  and theres one in the list I referenced

Comment: @FasihKhatib - Why are you on the ATI website you should be installing the drivers listed by HP.  They have been tested by HP.